# Digits of precision for elements of a matrix

Tags: output-formatting, output

I am looking for a way to control the precision of numbers that are elements in a matrix, or list of numbers. Something similar to `NumberForm[...]` but so that I can use it in conjunction with `MatrixForm[...]`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(m = RandomReal[99, {3, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
NumberForm[m // MatrixForm, {5, 2}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** See Properties & Relations section of documentation for [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html)

Comment: That easy huh? Nice, thanks!!